# Why are Ubuntu addresses of NTP pools supplied when they do not work?

Tags: networking, server, ntp

See:

```
$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 2.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 3.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
+213.95.200.107  213.95.151.123   2 u   87  256  377    4.874   -0.408   0.127
-37.221.192.191  131.188.3.221    2 u  187  256  377    4.806   -0.473   0.309
-vpn88.smart-met 193.190.230.66   2 u  243  256  377    5.192   -0.788   0.118
*ntp.etech.haw-h .PPS.            1 u  191  256  377   14.925    1.388   0.188
+formularfetisch 192.53.103.104   2 u  170  256  377    6.055   -0.287   0.127
```

Answer (score 6):

They are working. The reason they give zero values in delays, etc are that they are *pools*.

The server addresses below:

```
+213.95.200.107  213.95.151.123   2 u   87  256  377    4.874   -0.408   0.127
-37.221.192.191  131.188.3.221    2 u  187  256  377    4.806   -0.473   0.309
-vpn88.smart-met 193.190.230.66   2 u  243  256  377    5.192   -0.788   0.118
*ntp.etech.haw-h .PPS.            1 u  191  256  377   14.925    1.388   0.188
+formularfetisch 192.53.103.104   2 u  170  256  377    6.055   -0.287   0.127
```

... come from these pool addresses that gather several servers and provide them to the OS.